# DFT phase and amplitude by using vhdl core in FPGA

Tags: vhdl, signal-processing, fft, xilinx, dft

How to find out phase and amplitude of an analogue waveform ?
I am  receiving one analogue signal from one sensor, by using that analogue waveform I want to find out DFT (phase, amplitude) for fundamental frequency and the second harmonic. I converted the analogue signal through ADC applied to FPGA. In that FPGA I want to use IP DFT 4.0 core, but the DFT core output is only imaginary and real values. By using this how can I determine phase and amplitude of fundamental and harmonics?

Answer (score 0):

For each complex (re, im) output you can calculate magnitude and phase like this:

```
magnitude = sqrt(re*re + im*im);
phase = atan2(im, re);
```

If you know the frequency of your fundamental (and harmonics) then you can just calculate the appropriate FFT output bin index using the formula:

```
i = N * f / Fs
```

where `N` is the FFT size, `f` is the frequency of interest and `Fs` is the sample rate.

Comment: how can we find out for second harmonic by using IP DFT 4.0 core in FPGA ? if possible go through the DFT 4.0 ip core. is it possible those calculations(magnitude = sqrt(re*re + im*im);
phase = atan2(im, re);) in VHDL.?

Comment: You might be able to do this with some additional logic on your FPGA, or you could just pass the DFT results back to your host CPU for final processing, since there is very little computation involved compared to the FFT itself.

Comment: thank for your patience for giving me the solution MR Paul R sir, 1). Here i am giving an anlog signal via adc to FPGA. and i want to process that analog signal by using DFT core 4.0 ip and my results should be amplitude and phase of I harmonic and same for II harmonic. But in the data sheet of IP core DFT4.0 outputs are only real and imaginary values.  2).the processed data we will display in GUI via RS232/422. if we need any small multiplication we will do on GUI. what kind of logic we have to use in fpga to find out phase and amplitude of  I harmonic as well for II harmonic ? please describ

Comment: I already explained above - just send the real/imag FFT output data to your host PC and calculate phase and magnitude of the required components there, using the above formulae.